# Rails collection_select vs f.collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-for

I can't understand the difference between the two. Can someone please explain the difference when using form_for?

Say you have this: `<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>`

Examples- When would you use this?

`<%= collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, prompt: true) %>`

vs. use this?

`<%= f.collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, prompt: true) %>`

[Rails Api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select)

Comment: The f. in general is used for indicating the form with the object related to it, in collection_select tag case, it takes the object so the f. is not needed, I think (that's why I'm commenting :P) that's the correct answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `f.some_form_helper` the helper will already know the name of the model you want to make the field name for. This way you can drop that `:post` argument. `form_for(@post)` gives you the `f` form builder object that knows what model the form is for.

With the regular `collection_select` (or any other helper with `f.`) you have to pass in, as the first argument, the name of the model the field is for.

Your example is a bit off because you passed in the same arguments to both. `f.collection_select` doesn't need the `:post`.

This is correct use of the **non** `f.` helper:

```
<%= collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, prompt: true) %>
```

This is a corrected way to use the `f.` helper:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, prompt: true) %>
```

the `f` object has a reference back to the model you passed in to `form_for` via `f.object`. This is how it knows to call `collection_select(:post, ...)` under the hood.